# Convert part of a raster file to .asc file

Tags: qgis, raster, ascii, profile, cross-section

I'm a bit new at this. I have a DEM map (.tif) of an area in QGIS. I know that I can transform it to a text file (.asc) with `raster -> translate`.

However, what I need is only a certain cross-section of the area. So I want to choose a straight line, with specific coordinates, and get an .asc file containing the data of only the points along this line.

Comment: I think  what you need is a keyword "profile" to search within this GIS SE. With the same keyword you can find nice plugins at [Plugins Repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment above mentions, there is a `Profile Tool` plugin available in QGIS, which allows you to plot a line across a raster (in this case DTM). See below to install the plugin:

[image]

It will return a graph of the terrain profile as well as a Table with the elevation values along that line (which you can copy to a clipboard including the coordinates) and then paste to a text file. See example below:

[image]

You can also export the corresponding graph to a PDF or PNG:

[image]